# Attempting to spawn on exe in unpacked asar results in the exe being unpacked to a temp directory?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an electron application that I'm packaging up with electron-builder.

Within that application there is a distribution of an exe that I want to be able to call from electron.

The `build` section of my package.json includes an `asarUnpack` property, like so:

```
"asarUnpack": [
  "**/node_modules/dist-myexe.exe/**/*",
],
```

This means that when my application is installed, the exe is extracted under
`C:\Program Files\MyElectronApp\resources\app.asar.unpacked\node_modules\myexe.exe\vendor\myexe.exe`.

However, when I attempt to `child-process.spawn` on that exe, windows attempts to run a version from:
`%APPDATA%\Local\Temp\par-blahblahblah\cache-blahblahblah\myexe.exe`

I'm wondering if this is related to: https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/12092

Is this expected behaviour for electron apps? How can I target the exe that is in Program Files instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exe I was trying to execute on was exiftool.exe, which is actually the culprit extracting to Temp, not electron.